# Umbraco library getMedia parent node property xslt

Tags: xslt, properties, umbraco, parent

How can I get a property from the parent node of a media item using "umbraco.library:GetMedia"?

This allows me to get the current nodes "@nodeName"

```
<xsl:value-of select="umbraco.library:GetMedia(., 0)/@nodeName" />
```

I want to get the parent of the current nodes "@nodeName", I've tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
<xsl:value-of select="umbraco.library:GetMedia(., 0)/../@nodeName" />
```

Can anyone help me out?

Cheers, JV

Comment: The parent of the current node's @nodeName would be the current node itself.  Did you mean you want the @nodeName for the parent of the current node? Have you tried: `<xsl:value-of select="umbraco.library:GetMedia(.., 0)/@nodeName" />`?  Could you show us a bit more of your XSLT so we have some idea what the `.` here is referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a call to GetMedia() and the @parentID attribute in a variable, I've got it working using the following:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
        <!-- Do not call unless an image was picked -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$currentPage/image[normalize-space()]" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="image">
        <!-- Note: These WILL fail if no media is selected -->
        <xsl:variable name="mediaNode" select="umbraco.library:GetMedia(., false())" />
        <xsl:variable name="parentMedia" select="umbraco.library:GetMedia($mediaNode/@parentID, false())" />

        <p>
                Media: <xsl:value-of select="$mediaNode/@nodeName" />
        </p>
        <p>
                Parent: <xsl:value-of select="$parentMedia/@nodeName" />
        </p>
</xsl:template>
```